# Using metro ui css to build a profile page

Tags: metro-ui-css

has anyone built a profile using metro ui css, i need some inspiration for an online management system using metro and not able to come across much online. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily using the Metro UI CSS however these examples will hopefully provide inspiration that you could use to design your own.

Metro drew on clean typography and geometry - heavy use of the grid system and white-space. As Metro has matured it's moved on from the original designs, however Microsoft have continued to champion those original concepts - check out [their guidelines for developing apps](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design), and you might find exploring their products [Windows Phone](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design), [Xbox One](http://www.theverge.com/2017/1/16/14284336/microsoft-xbox-one-dashboard-update-2017), and the [Windows 10 redesign that got leaked](http://www.theverge.com/2017/1/5/14176806/microsoft-windows-10-project-neon-design) - This one in-particular has quite a few ideas for profiles.

I first started reading about Metro from [Long Zheng's blog - istartedsomething.com](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20100316/a-look-at-metro-the-book/). And through him I discovered [Mike Guss](http://mike-guss.com). Guss was one of the initial designers of the Metro language. He's recently updated his website and has some great Metro work on there:

- http://mike-guss.com/#windows-phone
- http://mike-guss.com/#xbox-one-1

Apparently there are quite a few "Metro" front-ends, inspiration found here: https://www.sitepoint.com/metro-bootstraps/

A couple examples here:
https://juliankay.com/development/the-metro-inspired-interface/

And more here:
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=metro+inspired+user+interface

Comment: thanks for the references and response, they are good to lead on a suitable path to follow...other than just the online docs.